# NSAttributedString drawAtPoint and drawInRect - Discrepancies

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, nsview, nstextview

In the following images, the first character of each line is an NSAttributed string drawn in a subview.  The rest of the line is drawn in a regular NSTextView.

The subviews have the exact same height and origin as the line fragments in the NSTextView.

These are the results calling [NSATtributedString drawAtPoint:lineFragment.origin]

[image]

These are the results calling [NSAttributedString drawInRect:lineFragmentRect]
[image]

Can anyone explain the discrepancies to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default field editor's layout manager for NSTextField uses a different typesetter behavior setting than the default NSTextView.

Comment: Ah... thank you for the insight! Instead of a NSTextView, drawAtPoint renders text within an NSTextField.